# responsive design with windows height 100% and push sibling divs when parent divs content is greater than defined height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<section>
   <div class="section-wrap">
     <h1>page1</h1>
   </div>
</section> 
<section>
   <div class="section-wrap">
    <h1>page2</h1>
   </div>
</section>
```

I tried following `javascript` but only works when div content is less than defined height

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    var wrapperH = $('section').height();
    if(windowH > wrapperH) {                            
        $('section').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
    }                                                                               
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowH = $(window).height();
        var wrapperH = $('section').height();
        var differenceH = windowH - wrapperH;
        var newH = wrapperH + differenceH;
        var truecontentH = $('.section-wrap').height();
        if(windowH > truecontentH) {
            $('section').css('height', (newH)+'px');
        }

    })          
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Can add some more detail about what the current behavior is, and what it should be?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/td3dqoLd6d#

content overlaps following section when contents height is more than browser height

Comment: I still don't really understand the problem. Do you want the height of a section to be at least the same height than the viewport, but be still big enough to fit all the content? In that case, don't use JS, it can be done by CSS: `section {min-height: 100vh; }` - but this does not work in mobile Safari in iOS 7 (and 6?) because of the vh-unit. There are workarounds, however - for example, you could just change the min-height of sections with JS whenever the window resizes.

Comment: thanks  Jost,  section {min-height: 100vh; } works fine for me is there any other way to support all devices and ie8+

Answer (score 0):

To make section elements always have at least the height of the viewport, use this CSS:

```
section {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

It is pretty [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), even IE supports it from version 9 upwards. There is one notable exception: mobile Safari in iOS 7 has buggy support.

To circumvent this problem, you can use JavaScript. Either by using a polyfill or something similar to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        jQuery('section').css('min-height', windowHeight + 'px');
    });
});
```

However, this will stop working without JS. I also believe that it could be quite computation intensive.

Another approach would be to add rules like this to your CSS:

```
@media (min-height: 1000px) {
    section {
        min-height: 1000px;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 1010px) {
    section {
        min-height: 1010px;
    }
}

// Same for many other heights.
```

The problem here would be maintainability, because you'd need way over 100 rules. But that can be tackled using a CSS preprocessor. In LESS it could look like this:

```
.min-height-100vh(@height) when @height > 0 {
    @media (min-height: @height) {
        min-height: @height;
    }

    .min-height-100vh(@height - 10px);
}

section {
    .min-height-100vh(3000px);
}
```

That would generate about 300 media queries, which increases the stylesheet size and could also increase the needed processing power.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i figured out the solution, this worked on ie8+ and all browsers plus mobile devices as well

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>section 1</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>section 2</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```